# explain the syntax for empty delimiter

Tags: python, delimiter

I am reading a book and below is a small code provided in it:

```
>>>S='shrubbery'
>>>L=list(S)
>>>L
>>>['s', 'h', 'r', 'u', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'y']
>>>L[1]='c'
>>>''.join(L)
'scrubbery'
```

Can someone explain me the syntax of last command ''.join(L)
I understand what's its doing ..but its kind of weird ... which one is object or class in this command? is '' a string object and join()the method ....

thanks

Comment: Join without a space in between each character.

Comment: Yes, `''` is a string object and `join` is a method. Sounds like you do understand it!

Comment: Whatever happened to `help(str.join)`?

Comment: `''.join(L)` is essentially equivalent to `str.join('', L)`, so `str` is the class and `''` is the object(instance).

Comment: @Blorgbeard - thanks a lot. I kind of needed confirmation if I am understanding it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join):

```
str.join(iterable)
```

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in the iterable `iterable`. The separator between elements is the string (`str`) providing this method.

So `''.join(L)` joins the elements of `L`, separating them from each other by the empty string.

You might wonder why this method seems so backwards (for example, why not `L.join('')`? The reason is simple: The result will always be a string, and the separator will always be a string. And since the method should work on *any* iterable that can provide a string representation of its members, it makes sense to define it once on the string separator instead of multiple times for each possible iterable.

Answer (score 2):

The `join` method of a string `str` causes the list of strings passed to it to be joined into a single string using the `str` string, i.e. `','.join(['1', '2', '3'])` will return `'1,2,3'`.

`''` is an empty string, thus the list of strings will be joined using an empty delimiter, i.e. `''.join(['1', '2', '3'])` returns `'123'`.